# A line that is not parallel

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose that **n** points are given. Call the set of lines determined by them **S**. Can you find a line that is not parallel to any of the lines in **S** in better than quadratic time?

Comment: At first glance, no: you already need quadratic time (in the number of points) to enumerate the lines in S.

Comment: Please clarify your question. How are the lines determined from the points? What variable does the stated time complexity refer to (quadratic in what)?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: this argument does not hold, nothing says that you have to enumerate the lines.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: **n**, of course.

Comment: I hear you @YvesDaoust, what approach would you use that does not enumerate the lines?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: compare to the following problem: given an array of values, find the pair with the smallest difference.

Comment: noted, thank you @YvesDaoust, appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: n'en faisons pas un fromage ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort all **n** points by increasing abscissa. It is clear that the largest slope occurs between two consecutive points. So pick the largest slope among the **n-1** possibilities and use a yet larger slope.

[image]

---

The case of points vertically aligned is harmless: ignore these infinite slopes and stay with the largest among the finite ones.

Comment: @k: yep, the cost of sorting dominates. If the points are pre-sorted or if a faster sort is possible (radix sort ?), then O(N).